# How to properly import Firestore with TypeScript and Node?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, import, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building an Angular web app, and I was importing like this:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
db = firebase.firestore();
```

But lately I keep getting this error:

```
It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS SDK.
When deploying Firebase apps to production, it is advisable to only import the 
individual SDK components you intend to use.

For the module builds, these are available in the following manner
(replace <PACKAGE> with the name of a component - i.e. auth, database, etc):

Typescript:
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/<PACKAGE>';
```

and so, naturally, I changed it to this:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
db = firebase.firestore();
```

but the error didn't go away. I don't understand how to remove it?

Comment: Modify the first line to import firebase from 'firebase/app';

Comment: Why not just use something like @angular/fire that handles the imports and initialization as well as advanced subscriptions for you?

Comment: When I do `import firebase from 'firebase/app';` I get the tslint error `Module '"c:/myApp/node_modules/firebase/index"' has no default export`

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky @angular/fire doesn't have some of the necessary utilities like getting the server timestamp.

Comment: I can’t comment on every specific feature in @angular/fire, but you definitely create firebase server timestamps. I’d personally done it in @angular/fire projects. Either way, happy coding.

Answer (score 3):

**Background**

That warning message is only triggered if you're loading the all firebase modules like you are in your first code snippet. It's best practice to only use bare imports like you changed it to:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
```

This imports just the `firestore` module.

**Solution**

Search your imports in any files you changed for `from 'firebase'`. Even code like `import {firestore} from 'firebase';` would trigger the warning message.